# How interpret Storm UI statistic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have some problems with interpreting storm UI stats.
I've deployed a simple topology with Kafka spout and Custom Bolt that do nothing, but acknowledge tuples. The idea was to measure performance of Kafka spout.

[image: Storm UI statistic]

So, looking at this stats I've got some questions.

1) In last 10 min topology acked 1619220 tuples and complete latency was 14.125ms. But if you make some calculations:

```
    (1619220 * 14.125) / (1000 * 60) = 381
```

1619220 tuples with complete latency 14.125 each, requires 381 min to pass topology. But that stats was on last 10 minutes. Complete latency shows wrong number, or I interpret it wrong?

2) Bolt capacity is around 0.5. Does it proof that bottleneck is kafka spout?

I will appreciate any information about improving storm topology perfomace, since it's not obvious for me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tuples processing does overlap for many tuples in-flight due to parallelism, your calculation is not correct. (It would only be correct, if Storm would process a single tuple completely before starting with the next tuple.)

A capacity on 0.5 is not really an overload. Overload would be more than 1. But I would suggest to try to keep it below 0.9 or maybe 0.8 to get some head room for spikes in you input rate.

Comment: Thanks for answer Matthias. One more thing. In question about capacity I wasn't sure about spout not bolt. Does the capacity value 0,5 of bolt shows that spout runs as fast as it can and I need to increase its parallelism hint?

Comment: This could be the case. But only if there is enough data available that the spout can fetch from external and emit.